# How to add a custom variable with apache logs?

Tags: apache, logging

How to add custom variable name with apache logs so that I can add my project name with my error logs in beginning, it is helpful for recognizing error logs with project name. I have lot of projects in my organization and project can be build in any language, I want to track all logs on a one place, but issue is that which errors are coming from which projects, i am unable to get it, so I want to add project name with logs. please suggest me, if any documentation is there, so i can manipulate apache then share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Access Log is using a log format defined by [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive.

This format can contain [a lot of things](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats). One of theses things is `%{VARNAME}e` : The contents of the environment variable VARNAME. So using [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) on your application VirtualHosts you could manage your goals.

But this does not work for ErrorLog. If you manage applications with Virtualhosts you should use separate ErrorLog files on theses Virtualhosts.